# Speed of matrix multiplication in R

Tags: multithreading, r, performance, fortran, matrix-multiplication

Until today, I was convinced that for large problems, one need to resort to C++, C or Fortran. However, in a recent benchmark, I got the result for `a %*% t(a)`, where `a` is a lower triangular matrix of 18000x18000 of class `dgCMatrix`, in 5 seconds using the r-evolution package and multi-threading.

However, even when using Intel ifort compiler, parallel computing and BLAS routines built into the MKL library, the Fortran code always need about a minute for the same problem. Does anyone know what the trick is, and how to make use of it in pure languages like C or Fortran?

### Specifications

- compiler: ifort 14.0
- mkl:

  - version 11.1
  - in the module header of the fortran code: use mkl95_blas, only trmm
  - the compiler options: -i8 -I$(MKLROOT)/include/intel64/ilp64 -I$(MKLROOT)/include
  - the linker options: $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_blas95_ilp64.a \
    -Wl,--start-group $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a \
    $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a \
    $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a \
    -Wl,--end-group -liomp5 -lpthread -lm
  - in addition in both, compling and linking: -i-static -O3 -parallel
- local BLAS

  - f77 BLAS library
  - compiled with -O3 -parallel

Comment: With differences like that, perhaps you have issues with cache collisions.

Comment: [dgCMatrix](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/dgCMatrix-class.html) is for sparse matrices, BLAS is for dense matrices. No wonder there is some speed difference... And anyway, dgCMatrix is written in C, so your previous assumption is not contradicted.

Comment: I called the trmm blas function (a f90 wrapper around dtrmm) as trmm(a,a,"L","L","N") where a is the matrix. dtrmm is actually for multiplying a blas function for multiplying a triangular matrix with a dense matrix. Even in sparse blas, routines are only available for sparse x dense. Thus, I can hardly imagine that using sparse blas will have any performance advantage compared to using "triangular" blas.

Comment: Is your matrix dense? (I mean, the lower triangular part of course) Btw, it occupies 1.2G of memory, then.

Comment: By the way, calling [dtrmm](http://for2html.sourceforge.net/BLAS/dtrmm.html) with the same matrix for A and B looks a bit dangerous as the function updates B.

Comment: Yest, the lower triangular part is dense. It is a Cholesky matrix. I forgot to write that I make a copy of a for the second matrix in the subroutine call. The memory issue should affect both, R routines as well as Fortran code

Comment: Ok, I am closer to the solution. I included a external blas library compiled on my computer. Compared to the benmark of the mkl (1 minute) I got the result from the dtrmm function in four seconds, which is slightly faster than R. The world has turned upside up again. Cheers and thanks

Comment: OT instead of `a %*% t(a)` recommended way is `tcrossprod(a)`

Comment: can you update your question? What MKL version do you use, what processor, how do you link, do you use threaded MKL, what are your runtime parameters (OMP_NUM_THREADS)?

Comment: @user1407220. Now that you have better results with dtrmm, it would be nice to give a clue about what you did (as asked by steabert), in order to understand why your previous program was so slow.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late update

Comment: Just out of interest, did you try [OpenBLAS](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS) instead of BLAS? I have seen that it can be considerably faster than the MKL...

Comment: can you use the f77 MKL interface and libraries? I wonder if it could have something to do with copying the matrix depending on how the routines are called. Can you post your program as well?

Comment: Yes, I can. If you browse the subdirectories below the mkl folder, you will find an interface file defining f90 interfaces for all the f77 blas funcitons. That's why "use mkl_95blas" must be included in the source code. Sorry, can't post the program, too large